# How to specify a StyleSheet of a newly programmatically-created notebook?

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting

I would like to make a button that opens a notebook upon pressing. The point is that I would like the notebook to be made according to a specified StyleSheet.

To be more specific, here is a simple example of such a button:

```
    Button["Show",
 CreateDocument[
  Column[{
    TextCell["Some text" , "Text", FontSize -> 20],
    ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
    }],
  WindowTitle -> "Some title", WindowSize -> {450, 300}], 
 ImageSize -> {50, 18}, BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", Bold}]
```

The button is then copy-pasted into any line of any TextCell of the main notebook and serves for the referencing purposes: when the reader meets the text discussing this plot this button in embedded in such a text, and he may press the button. This will generate the notebook with  the plot, and the reader may see the plot in question on the spot.

Now, I would like the notebook that will be open that way to be created according to the JournalArticle StyleSheet. Is it possible to specify?

This edit I am making after having received the answers of Mike Honeychurch and m_goldberg. After all corrections here is the code I had in mind:

```
    Clear[x, y, z];
Button["Show a JournalArticle Notebook",
 CreateDocument[{
   (* This makes a Section title *)
   TextCell["A section", "Section", FontSize -> 40],
   (* This makes a text *)
   TextCell["Some text", "Text", FontSize -> 20],
   (* This makes a numbered formula *)
   TextCell[y == Sin[x^2] // TraditionalForm, 
    "DisplayFormulaNumbered", FontSize -> 20, TextAlignment -> Center],
   (* This makes a plot *)
   ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], "Figure"],
   (* This makes a caption for illustration *)
   TextCell["Some caption", "FigureCaption", FontSize -> 14],
   (* This makes another numbered formula *)
   TextCell[z == Exp[-x^2] // TraditionalForm, 
    "DisplayFormulaNumbered", FontSize -> 20, TextAlignment -> Center]
   },
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{"Article"}, "JournalArticle.nb", 
    CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], WindowTitle -> "Some title", 
  WindowSize -> {750, 500}, Background -> LightYellow], 
 ImageSize -> {200, 18}, BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", Bold}]
```

It creates a button. The latter opens the notbook. That's how it looks like: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Button["Show", 
  CreateDocument[
    Column[{
      TextCell["Some text", "Text", FontSize -> 20], 
      ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]}],
    StyleDefinitions -> 
      FrontEnd`FileName[{"Article"}, "JournalArticle.nb", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"],
    WindowTitle -> "Some title",
    WindowSize -> {450, 300}],
  ImageSize -> {50, 18},
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", Bold}]
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike. This solution, however, does not do what I expected from it. I mean that the notebook open that way does not show the formatting I expect from the one in the JournalArticle style. Please see the end below

Comment: Indeed this: Clear[y, x];
Button["Show",
 CreateDocument[Column[{
    TextCell["A Section name", "Section", FontSize -> 20],
    TextCell[y == x^2, "DisplayFormulaNumbered", FontSize -> 20],
    TextCell["Some text", "Text", FontSize -> 20],
    ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], "Figure"]}],
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{"Article"}, "JournalArticle.nb", 
    CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], WindowTitle -> "Some title", 
  WindowSize -> {650, 500}], ImageSize -> {50, 18}, 
 BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", Bold}]  shows no expected formatting when open.

Comment: Further, if I add this statement after the ExpressionCell one: TextCell["A caption for illustration", "FigureCaption", 
 FontSize -> 20], the button cannot open anything at all. Can you see the workaround?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch. This code does exactly what it promises on my system, which is V9.0.1 running on OS X 10.6.8. Just don't wrap your list of cells with `Column`.

Comment: @Mike Honeychurch OK, without Column it, indeed, works perfectly. What is the role of CharacterEncoding here?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I addressed the stylesheet issue and didn't look at the code in the `Createdocument`. Remember notebooks are constructed as sequences of cells and/or cellgroups so using `Column` simply creates an undefined (in the stylesheet) cell for the stuff to reside in -- which you can see if you use Show Expression.

Comment: @Mike Honeychurch Thank you. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Honeychurch's answer solves your problem concerning setting the notebook style sheet. Your other problems stem from using `Column` to wrap your list of cells. The following, I believe, will deliver a popup notebook with the formatting you want.

```
Button["Show", 
  CreateDocument[{
    TextCell["Fox Plot", "Section"],
    TextCell["The quick brown fox made this plot.", FontSize -> 16, "Text"], 
    ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]}, 
    StyleDefinitions -> 
      FrontEnd`FileName[{"Article"}, "JournalArticle.nb", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], 
    WindowTitle -> "How to Fox Plot",
    WindowSize -> {500, 320}],
  ImageSize -> {50, 20},
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 12, Bold}]
```

[image: button.png]

[image: foxplot.png]

Comment: You are right, thank you.